# Return Specific dates from Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with report data. Each date contains 5 entries for each day as there is Group1 to Group5 in the GroupID column.

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [date] NULL,
[GroupID] [int] NULL,
[GroupName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[GroupDescription] [varchar](500) NULL,
[GroupCount] [int] NULL
```

So the table looks like this and is populated every Monday:

| Date | GroupID | GroupName | GroupDescription | GroupCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-04 | 1 | Group1 | Group1 Description | 49358 |
| 2022-04-04 | 2 | GROUP2 | Group2 Description | 6158 |
| 2022-04-04 | 3 | GROUP3 | Group3 Description | 2572 |
| 2022-04-04 | 4 | GROUP4 | Group4 Description | 181 |
| 2022-04-04 | 5 | GROUP5 | Group1 Description | 15580 |
| 2022-04-12 | 1 | Group1 | Group1 Description | 49358 |
| 2022-04-12 | 2 | GROUP2 | Group2 Description | 6158 |
| 2022-04-12 | 3 | GROUP3 | Group3 Description | 2572 |
| 2022-04-12 | 4 | GROUP4 | Group4 Description | 181 |
| 2022-04-12 | 5 | GROUP5 | Group1 Description | 15580 |

I want to write a query and put it into a Stored Procedure that will produce the following

I will pass the stored procedure an int, normally 4 that will give me the last 4 Mondays (or unique date entries in case of bank holiday etc so it might update on a Tuesday)

| Date | Group1 | Group2 | Group3 | GROUP4 | Group5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-28 | 49358 | 6158 | 2572 | 181 | 15580 |
| 2022-04-04 | 49358 | 6158 | 2572 | 181 | 15580 |
| 2022-04-12 | 49358 | 6158 | 2572 | 181 | 15580 |
| 2022-04-19 | 49358 | 6158 | 2572 | 181 | 15580 |

I haven't tried anything as I'm not really sure where to start or if that's even possible.

Comment: Can be done. You can start here (PIVOT and UNPIVOT): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Great thanks I'll give that a go. Not been doing this long so appreciate giving me the pointer.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution. I'm not sure if I should put the resulting script in the comment or answer my question but happy to share it if anyone wants to see it.

Comment: Happy to help! I would put the code / solution as an answer and mark it as accepted (You can answer/accept your own question) and (still) add value here for future visitors. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Eduard for the pointer. The solution was a Pivot table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    [GROUPNAME],
    [DATE],
    [GROUPCOUNT]
  FROM ReportAccountGroup
) ReportResults
PIVOT (
  SUM(GroupCount)
  FOR [GroupName]
  IN (
    [Group1],
    [Group2],
    [Group3],
    [Group4],
    [Group5]
  )
) AS PivotTable
```

The first section get's the data. Second Section in PIVOT Sets the values for the columns.
The SUM(GroupCount) is an aggregate function to supply the grouped results.